# Controlling an Adobe Air application with an external program

Tags: air, adobe, controls, monitor, spy++

Is there a way to control or monitor components of an Adobe Air application, with native application I can easily use Spy++ to find the components of a window and control/monitor it using windows API but I couldn't find anything that can be of use for an Adobe Air application since Spy++ can only see the window and the rest is an SWF file.

What I needed to do is check a button state so I can startup my application. The Air application is a chat program which doesn't have a recording function, I'm done with the recording part, what is left is when and how to trigger it.

Comment: I am unable to understand your question. Do you want to trigger external program from Air application or other application triggering AIR application?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm looking at this now. Trying to read some UI elements state from an Adobe Air app. Spy++ only shows the ApolloRuntimeContentWindow. I know this is because Air doesn't use native windows api, but did you find a way?